# COUNT() is multiplying the the two individual column counts together, how do I get this to not happen?

Tags: sql, count, ssms, aggregate-functions

Here are the tables:
CUSTOMER

```
custid(PK) custname custtype
001        john     null
002        rob      1
```

CITY

```
cityid(PK) cityname
001        Baltimore
002        Knoxville
```

PACKAGE

```
packageid(PK) custid(PK,FK) cityid
001           001           001
001           002           001
002           001           002
```

Now my query is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITYNAME, CUSTTYPE, COUNT(P.PACKAGEID) AS PACKAGE_COUNT
FROM CITY S LEFT OUTER JOIN PACKAGE P 
ON S.CITYID=P.CITYID,
CUSTOMER C INNER JOIN PACKAGE Q 
ON C.CUSTID=Q.CUSTID
GROUP BY CITYNAME, CUSTTYPE;
```

Result:

```
CITYNAME  CUSTTYPE PACKAGE_COUNT
BALTIMORE NULL     4
KNOXVILLE NULL     2
BALTIMORE 1        2
KNOXVILLE 1        0
```

What I would like to see is:

```
CITYNAME  CUSTTYPE PACKAGE_COUNT
BALTIMORE NULL     1
KNOXVILLE NULL     1
BALTIMORE 1        1
KNOXVILLE 1        0
```

From what I could tell the cityname count is being multiplied by the custtype count i.e baltimore = 2 and null = 2 hence 2*2 = 4. Even though in the package table baltimore only receives one package from a null custtype. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just run first part of the query without group by and see what it yields. SELECT CITYNAME, CUSTTYPE, P.PACKAGEID 
FROM CITY S LEFT OUTER JOIN PACKAGE P 
ON S.CITYID=P.CITYID,
CUSTOMER C INNER JOIN PACKAGE Q 
ON C.CUSTID=Q.CUSTID

Comment: I understand what you mean the query over duplicates records when I run the first part of the query but if I add DISTINCT clause to CITYNAME it fixes that but doesn't fix the issue when the aggregate function is re-included in the query, but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate all the rows using a cross join then do the left join and aggregation:

```
SELECT C.CITYNAME, CT.CUSTTYPE, COUNT(P.PACKAGEID) AS PACKAGE_COUNT
FROM CITY S CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT CUSTTYPE FROM CUSTOMER) CT LEFT OUTER JOIN
     PACKAGE P 
     ON S.CITYID = P.CITYID AND CT.CUSTID = P.CUSTID
GROUP BY C.CITYNAME, CT.CUSTTYPE;
```